# P/Invoke on 32 bit and 64 bit systems

Tags: .net, winapi, x86, pinvoke, 64-bit

Let us pick the following Win API call as an example:

```
BOOL MessageBeep(UINT uType); // from User32.dll
```

The input parameter is UINT to specify the beep type, which is can be both 32bit and 64bit integer, depending on which Windows version we call it on (*or am I wrong?*).

If I want to P/Invoke message beep from C#, so I apply the DllImport declaration:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
static extern Boolean MessageBeep(UInt32 beepType);
```

Will this code C# work under Windows x64?

- If yes, why is it OK to invoke the call a 32bit integer, while a 64bit integer is expected (assuming that I am correct on this)?
- If no, how should the proper platform agnostic P/Invoke declaration look like in C#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are wrong.

However, for types like `HANDLE` that do vary with bitness, you should use `IntPtr`.

If you're uncertain about a P/Inoke declaration, the first place to check is [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/).

Comment: Why is DWORD bitness dependent, and UINT not? It seems contrary to the C data type docs I read. Windows Data Types page on MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383751(VS.85).aspx

DWORD: typedef unsigned long DWORD; UINT: typedef unsigned int UINT;

Comment: To extend your answer, I found the following MSDN recommendation on 32/64bit safe coding:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384242(VS.85).aspx